How to convert PPTX to PDF on a Non-Windows machine
I'm sure many have come across this question, but I couldn't find any solutions for non-windows machines.
I need to prepare a Python script that can run on Linux (multiple versions) as well as On Windows machines. The script should read a PPT file, and convert it into a PDF, then convert the PDF into images. I can achieve the second part (PDF to images), but I can't achieve the first part (PPT to PDF).
Can anyone please help me to achieve this?
I tried Spire and Aspose, but both of them are commercial and we need to pay. Python pptx doesn't support conversion. Win32 is not available in Linux.
I am at a dead end.
This is the code I used to achieve the above (both the first and second parts) using the spire library, but it doesn't convert more than 10 pages.
!pip install Spire.Presentation

# Function to convert PPT to Images
def ppt_to_images(ppt_file, destination_folder):
    presentation = Presentation()
    presentation.LoadFromFile(ppt_file)
    presentation_name = ppt_file.split('/')[-1].split('.')[0]
    #Save PPT document to images
    for i, slide in enumerate(presentation.Slides):
        file_name = presentation_name + '_' + str(i) + ".png"
        image = slide.SaveAsImage()
        image.Save(destination_folder + '/' + file_name)
        image.Dispose()
    presentation.Dispose()
    return None

ppt_to_images("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/DummyPPTs/dummy_powerpoint.pptx", OUTPUT_FOLDER)

Calling the above function using
ppt_to_images("/content/drive/MyDrive/Colab Notebooks/DummyPPTs/dummy_powerpoint.pptx", OUTPUT_FOLDER)


That's going to be very difficult - the program that knows how to render PPTX files onto screen or into an image is, well, PowerPoint...

@AKX Thanks for the comment. Can I prepare a docker container of Windows and use WIN32 library?

Do you wish to convert PPTX to PDF (as implied by title) XOR PPT to PDF (as implied by can't achieve the first part (PPT to PDF).)?

Try this code to convert any pptx file to pdf
 import subprocess
 import os

 def convert_pptx_to_pdf(input_path, output_dir):
 if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
    os.makedirs(output_dir)

 # Construct the command to convert pptx to pdf
  command = [
    'libreoffice',
    '--headless',
    '--convert-to',
    'pdf',
    '--outdir',
    output_dir,
    input_path
]

# Execute the command
subprocess.run(command, check=True)
print(f'Converted {input_path} to PDF and saved in {output_dir}')

# Specify the path to the .pptx file and the output directory
pptx_path = 'presentation.pptx'
output_directory = 'Desktop'

# Convert the .pptx file to PDF
convert_pptx_to_pdf(pptx_path, output_directory)


This assumes you have libreOffice installed which is installed in default linux installation.

And assumes LibreOffice does a good job at this sort of conversion.

Also, did you try this? The indentation is very off.

Yes, I tested and it worked. Sorry indentation was messed during pasting

Hi @NaveedAhmed This is brilliant and it's working. I found another workaround to do this using unoconv.
command = '''unoconv -o "{0}" -f pdf "{1}"'''.format(destination_file, ppt_file)
os.system(command)
This works well in linux OS.
